# Can't Create Service Instance in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm trying to get the [introduction to spring cloud](https://spring.io/blog/2014/06/03/introducing-spring-cloud) app working with an instance of Cloud Foundry that I'm running on my machine. I tried to push the app and I get this message:

> Could not find service postgres-service to bind to hello-spring-cloud

So I started tracking down the postgres service.  When I run cf marketplace, I get

```
service      plans     description
mongodb      default   MongoDB NoSQL database
postgresql   default   PostgreSQL database
rabbitmq     default   RabbitMQ message queue
redis        default   Redis key-value store
```

I try to create a service instance of the postgresql service and I get:

```
cf create-service postgresql default postgresql-service
Creating service instance postgresql-service in org xyz / space development as admin...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 500, error code: 10001, message: Service broker error: Not authorized
```

I have tried running `cf create-service-auth-token postgresql core 123` but that didn't seem to help with the "Not Authorized" message.

I'm pretty new to Cloud Foundry so I'm a little lost.  How do I get my the sample app to bind to the postgresql service?

**update**

Here are the permissions for the space:

```
Getting users in org xyz / space development as admin

SPACE MANAGER
  admin

SPACE DEVELOPER
  admin
```

** update 2: cf service-access **

```
$ cf service-access
Getting service access as admin...
```

Then shows nothing on the terminal.  So I tried to enable service access...

```
$ cf enable-service-access postgresql
Enabling access to all plans of service postgresql for all orgs as admin...
All plans of the service are already accessible for all orgs
OK
```

But I still can't create the service.

Comment: I see that you are using the `admin` user to create the service instance, but to be sure, does that user have the space developer permission in your `development` space?

Comment: I assume `org xyz == org ge` as seen in your log?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Can you run `cf service-access` to see if your `default` service plan has been made public? If it is, the `access` column should say `all`. (I guess `limited` should work too for `admin`).

Comment: hmmm.. then I'm not sure what's going on. Try post a message to the CF [mailing list](https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/mailman/listinfo/cf-dev). You might get faster turnaround there.

Comment: Thanks for your time.  I appreciate the effort.  I'll see if the mailing list can help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there was a resolution to that, but it looks like an issue with deployment of the service broker for PostgreSQL (auth creds for service broker).

It can be checked/updated via

```
cf service-brokers
cf update-service-broker ...
```

or via redeployment of the service (via tile in PCF/bosh or whatever way you use)